# Controlling users' default printer as an administrator

Tags: linux, printing, cups

What are the necessary steps to change the default printer for individual users on a reasonably recent Linux system using CUPS? (i.e. not the system-wide default)

The CUPS `lpr` manpage indicates that setting the `PRINTER` environment variable is looked to first  by the printing system. But does this also affect the default printer for GNOME & KDE applications?

Does this also override whatever the user has changed by going to, for instance, the 'Printing' setup application in Ubuntu? Or the equivalent in RHED?

How can I cover all my bases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `lpoptions`. See `man lpoptions`.

The command looks like

```
lpoptions -d myprinter
```

and creates a line in  `~/.lpoptions` (or on some systems `~/.cups/lpoptions`) like

```
Default myprinter
```

See [Command-Line Printing and Options](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/options.html), section "Setting the Default Printer".